# Is it possible to FTP a ZIP folder from a SAS EG server session?

Tags: sas, ftp, zip

I am working on SAS server and I am able to successfully create a ZIP in my remote SAS user library by using ods commands. SAS shows the ZIP in my /sascode/user library and it is populated with 500kb of data using the following code:

```
filename csv_file "/sascode/user/file.csv"

ods package(newzip) open nopf;
ods package(newzip) add file=csv_file;
ods package(newzip) publish archive
  properties(
    archive_name="file.zip"
    archive_path="/sascode/user/"
);
ods package(newzip) close;
```

When I use a simple pipe to unzip the folder only 1 record is returned and it has the value of 1:

```
filename x pipe "unzip 'sascode/user/file.zip'
data _null_;
  infile x;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

So basically, there is not data inside according to SAS... even though SAS created the ZIP. Therefore, it is expected that when I FTP the file, the resulting ZIP is either empty or corrupt no matter what I try.

To FTP the file to a shared drive I have tried:

```
   ods listing close ;

   /* Use the Pipe command to pipe all of the body files generated and */
   /* all of the supporting files.                                     */

   filename zipit pipe 'zip  file.csv';

   data _null_;
      file zipit;
      put 'The will zip the files';
   run;
   filename zipit clear;

   /* FTP the zipped file created */
   filename moveit ftp '~my-user-id/test.zip' BINARY
            host='node.company.com' prompt debug
            user='my-user-id'
            pass='abc123';
   data _null_;
      file moveit;
      put;
   run;
   ods listing;
```

recfm=N is not a valid option in the above filename moveit portion of the code. This code successfully FTP's the ZIP, but it is corrupted.

```
data _null_;
infile zip_file;
file ftp_file;
input;
put _infile_;
```

With the proper filename  ftp commands of course. The ZIP folder appears in the expected shared drive folder with either 0 or 1kb of data compared to the 500kb present in my SAS user data folder.

I have also tried many variations of a null datastep with infile/file and playing around binary/nybte/recfm options to no avail.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is `zip` method in `filename` statement, ZIP Access Method(https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsglobal/n1dn0f61yfyzton1l2ngsa1clllr.htm)

Comment: Did you try RECFM=N ?

Comment: @Richard, when I add RECFM=N to either the FTP filename or the ZIP filename, I get an IO Error.  I am able to use binary as an FTP option however. That still results in a corrupt ZIP file in the expected FTP share drive.

Comment: What is the log output if you use `filename x pipe "unzip -l '/sascode/user/file.zip';`

Comment: it shows it contains one file of size 36328 with filename "/sascode/user/file.csv" , which looks correct

it also makes a csv I can open in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

`unzip` will extract files from the archive and create them in the current folder.

Use `unzip -l` to pipe the archive content listing to stdout for reading via infile.

Use `unzip -p` to pipe the binary contents to stdout (not useful).

If pipe is not available to your SAS session, use the zip file engine, dopen/dread/mopen/input/put to unzip the archive contents.

Comment: Thank you, I am still stuck on the FTP'd ZIP being corrupted.

Comment: so I able to ZIP and unzip the csv in SAS... something is just going wrong with the FTP

Comment: How are you ftp'ing ?

Comment: Updating post now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use SAS to copy a file, you need to use file I/O function. The following is an example to copy `C:\Profiles\XLab\PHSUG_2022.rar` to `C:\Profiles\new.rar`.

```
filename _from_ "C:\Profiles\XLab\PHSUG_2022.rar" recfm=n;
filename _to_ "C:\Profiles\new.rar" recfm=n;

data _null_;
  fid=fopen('_from_');
  if fid then do;
    fcopy=fcopy('_from_','_to_');
    if fcopy=0 then putlog 'NOTE: Copy successed.';
    else do;    *Put error message if copy failed;
      e=sysmsg();
      putlog e;
    end;
    fid=fclose(fid);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: what if I am trying to FTP the ZIP from my SAS server user folder (UNIX), to my desired shared Windows drive.